# Generating a Random Password containing both Numbers and Letters

Tags: php

I want to generate a **random** password of 15 characters that contains **BOTH** numbers and letters. Is there a simple way to do this?

I want to avoid a situation where I get all numbers in the password, but do not want to prefix the password with any letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate an array with a random number, a random character and 13 random chars/numbers and then use [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: I think you method looks feasible

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$pw = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 15);
```

I think it's very unlikely to end up with all numbers with this approach.

Comment: is there a chance that md5 would produce all numbers for the first 15 characters?

Comment: I do not know exactly how md5() works internally, but I don't think it will be likely.

Comment: you can run the function in a loop-until first character in [a-zA-Z]

Comment: Or something like `do {$pw = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 15);} while (preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $pw) || preg_match('/^[A-Z]*$/', $pw));` to generate passwords until you get one that's not all digits and not all letters.

Comment: That is massive overkill. The point was to not allow all numbers passwords, so you can just check it using `is_numeric($pw)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate the password in a loop till the length of password string you want. You can use rand() function within it to avoid the continues characters you can also use ASCII code for it with char() function

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Generates a highly random alphanumeric password of 15 chars.

```
$p = substr ( md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 15);
```

Comment: is there a chance that md5 would produce all numbers for the first 15 characters?